# Remove folder in Alfresco Share

Tags: javascript, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have created a `js` file to create folders when creating an event in `Alfresco`. But the problem is, when I create an event on the `Alfresco` site, it will automatically create a folder in a shared folder. That's a problem because when updating an existing event it creates a new folder without removing the existing folder. Also, when I delete an event it will not delete the corresponding folder.

How can I solve this problem?

Here is **my code** to create a new folder when an item is created:

```
// create a new folder in the same space
var folderNode = space.createFolder(document.properties["ia:whatEvent"]);

// copy the doc into the newly created folder node
//var copy = document.copy(folderNode);

// move the folder node to companyhome
var objDestFolder = companyhome.childByNamePath("Shared/SECRETARY/COMMISSION_PAPER_RECEIVED");
folderNode.move(objDestFolder);
```

Comment: var folderNode = space.createFolder(document.properties["ia:whatEvent"]); by using this code you are creating folder in Site or in Shared Folder ?

Comment: What is space object returns?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to create folder in the site than you need to specify the parent folder object where the new folder/document will get created.

like `docLibContainer.createFolder` for this docLibContainer is parent folder object.

In your case `space` is parent folder object.

Please try in this example `docLibContainer` will create a folder of name **document.properties["ia:whatEvent"]** in Document Library Folder.

```
 var site = document.getSiteShortName();
    var docLibContainer = siteService.getSite(site).getContainer("documentLibrary");

    if(docLibContainer){
        // create a new folder in the same space
        var folderNode = docLibContainer.createFolder(document.properties["ia:whatEvent"]);

        // copy the doc into the newly created folder node
        //var copy = document.copy(folderNode);

        // move the folder node to companyhome
        var objDestFolder = companyhome.childByNamePath("Shared/SECRETARY/COMMISSION_PAPER_RECEIVED");
        folderNode.move(objDestFolder);
    }else{
            // create a new folder in the same space
        var folderNode = space.createFolder(document.properties["ia:whatEvent"]);

        // copy the doc into the newly created folder node
        //var copy = document.copy(folderNode);

        // move the folder node to companyhome
        var objDestFolder = companyhome.childByNamePath("Shared/SECRETARY/COMMISSION_PAPER_RECEIVED");
        folderNode.move(objDestFolder);
    }
```